# Task Automation Help: (no similar entries)

Tags: python, automation

Problem: I’m a nurse, and part of my job is to pull up a list of “unsigned services”. Then of course, take these charts, and send them to the right person.

The person before me did not do this, leaving me THOUSANDS of charts to pull up by patient name and DOB, select the right document, and send to the right person.

I have figured out how to use selenium with python to automate logging in, using input to send keys to search the correct patient, and even to pull up the correct document that needs signed.

How do I have the program do this, for every chart? How do I have python work down the list of names and DOB’s without my having to manually put them in?

Anything I look for on my own is just examples of applying a basic function to a list of numbers and that isn’t my goal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The best way to approach tasks like this (assuming each chart is in the same format for Selenium) is usually to code the program to a single example, figure out what needs to change in between cases, and make that a variable. If you have a spreadsheet of patients and DOBs, you can probably convert it to a csv file (Excel can output one for you), have python read that in, and use the `csv` library to iterate over it and run your selenium routine as necessary for each patient (i.e. for each row in the csv)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have thought of this in theory, what would the code look like in practice? 

I have it set up as a loop right now, but I want the program to automatically move to the next row after I give it a command “enter”… any ideas?